# How do I display my git branch and commit status on my mac osx terminal?

Tags: git, terminal

I've seen numerous scripts to display the current branch but I'd like to replicate this exact set up [image: this exact set up] (see right side of screenshot). Does anyone know how to make it possible?

[link to full size screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgv5Y.png)

Comment: Just lookup whatever does it to your prompt? (BTW, what is the editor on the left side?)

Comment: Sublime text 2 (but this isn't my screenshot. I found this on hacker news).

Comment: Ah, thanks, meaning you can't lookup your setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).  It has different themes that can show the current git branch.  You can view screenshots of many of the currently available themes here: [themes](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)

Comment: It looks like the theme in your screenshot is the agnoster theme.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is something like

```
git describe --all --dirty=' ±'
```

Maybe not exactly what you need, but maybe you can work from that.